# Radius Search Results function in php

Tags: php

I have a search function on my site that takes the City State and Zip and searches a radius and displays the results found I have tested everything but it breaks at this line of this coding:

```
if ($origin_id[0] != -1)
        $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".OriginLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $origin_id) . ") ";
```

The Globals are defined and display correctly... If i do not put in the Radius it will display results for that city.. but with radius inputted it breaks...

I have included the Radius Function as well...

```
function GetLocationSearchCriteria(&$sql, &$urlappend, $prefix)
    {
        $origin_id = Location::GetLocationID($GLOBALS["OriginState"], $GLOBALS["OriginCity"], $GLOBALS["OriginZip"]);

        if (!is_array($origin_id))
        {
            $o = $origin_id;
            $origin_id = array();
            $origin_id[0] = $o;
        }

        if (!empty($GLOBALS["OriginRadius"]))
        {
            $origin = new Location($origin_id[0]);
----------->>>>>>   $origin_id = $origin->GetRadiusLocations($GLOBALS["OriginRadius"]);
            $urlappend .= "&OriginRadius=" . $GLOBALS["OriginRadius"];
        }

        // build query
        if ($origin_id[0] != -1)
            $sql .= " AND " . $prefix . ".OriginLocationID IN (" . implode(",", $origin_id) . ") ";
    }

    function GetRadiusLocations($radius)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT LocationID 
                    FROM locations 
                    WHERE (POW((69.1*(Longitude\"" . $this->Longitude . "\")*" . cos($this->Latitude/57.3) . "),\"2\")+POW((69.1*(Latitude-\"" . $this->Latitude . "\")),\"2\"))<(" . $radius * $radius . ") ";

            $conn = &$GLOBALS["dbSettings"]->GetConnection();
            $rs = &$conn->Execute($sql);
            if ($rs === false)
                return -1;
            $location_ids = array();
            while (!$rs->EOF)
            {
                array_push($location_ids, $rs->fields[0]);
                $rs->MoveNext();
            }
            return $location_ids;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution... i was missing a - after Longitude in the equation...

it should be this

(POW((69.1*(Longitude-\"" . $this->Longitude . "\")*" . cos($this->Latitude/57.3) . "),\"2\")+POW((69.1*(Latitude-\"" . $this->Latitude . "\")),\"2\"))<(" . $radius * $radius . ") ";